# Extracting Data from nav Tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to delete the data within a `nav` tag present in **scraped** data. I tried several methods and its extracting scuccessfully. But when I try to clean the rest of the data, the data from `nav` tag is also appearing. I tried `extract` and `decompose`  but all giving same results.

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.parse
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--incognito')

URL = "https://michiganopera.org/season-schedule/frida/"

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
z = soup.find("nav",{"class":"nav-main"})
z.extract()
for h in soup.find_all('header'):
    try:
        h.extract()
    except:
        pass
for f in soup.find_all('footer'):
    try:
        f.extract()
    except:
        pass
try:
    cols = soup.find("div",{"class":"modal fade"})
    cols.extract()
except:
    pass
text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')
print(text)
```

When we run this code, we will get cleaned data and out of this data there is a portion at the end like below which has to be removed

**Section to be removed**

```
 Sponsors 
 
 
 
 
 Email Sign Up View Calendar 
 
 
       Season & Tickets + Season at a Glance MOT at Home Upcoming + Dance Theatre of Harlem Calendar Ways to save + Subscriptions Groups Gift Certificates Box Office + How to Avoid Scalper Tickets Plan Your Visit + Parking & Directions + Sunday Shuttles Dining + Cadillac Café Hotels Opera & Dance Talks FAQ Online Boutique PLAN YOUR EVENT + Catering & Events Weddings Corporate & Social Event Sky Deck COVID-19 Safety Plan Get Involved + Community Events Young Patrons Circle Opera Teens Opera Clubs Ambassadors Volunteers Dance Film Series Learn + Summer Programs + Operetta Remix Dance Classes Children’s Choruses For Schools + Field Trips In-School Performances Classroom Guides Tours Allesee Resource Library Dance Dialogues MOT Learns at Home Support + Annual Fund & DiChiera Society Other Ways to Give Planned Giving David DiChiera Artistic Fund Sponsorship Opportunities Why I give to MOT About Us + Our History + MOT History DOH History Past Seasons David DiChiera Leadership + Board of Directors Wayne S. Brown Yuval Sharon Christine Goerke Admin & Staff + Our mission Antiracism Statement of Commitment Opera America Member Musicians + Orchestra Roster Chorus Roster Children’s Choruses Non-Profit Status Press
```

I am facing same issue with several sites.  I think I am missing some point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.parse
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--incognito')

URL = "https://michiganopera.org/season-schedule/frida/"

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
z = soup.find("nav",{"class":"nav-main"})
z.extract()
for h in soup.find_all('header'):
    try:
        h.extract()
    except:
        pass
for f in soup.find_all('footer'):
    try:
        f.extract()
    except:
        pass
try:
    cols = soup.find("div",{"class":"modal fade"})
    cols.extract()
except:
    pass
text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')
sep = 'Sponsors'
stripped = text.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(stripped)
```